# Django 1.9.7 Admin pages - CSS loaded but not rendering

Tags: css, django

I'm trying to get started with Django but already have something trivial bugging me.
The localhost:8000/admin page should give me page with rendered elements using the login.css and base.css styles. However, the styles are not applied.
Because my .css files are actually loading, I'm not even sure it's related to Django.

Any insight on what could be causing the issue greatly appreciated.

Django 9.1.7 / Python 3.5.0

Comment: You're saying that the Django admin page does not load the css files?

Comment: No, it did load it, it just didn't apply the styles.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the cause:

Django is using application x-css by default.

Adding these lines to settings.py

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)
```

solved the issue.